# The maximum number of developer applications on this phone has been reached

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I started a Windows 8 phone application and am trying to use a NEW phone as the device for debugging.

> Unable to install application. The maximum number of developer applications on this phone has been reached. Please uninstall a developer application and try again.

I registered the device so I do not know what the issue is. I have read about other people having the same issue but have not found a solution yet.

([Windows Phone App Deployment Issue](http://www.kunal-chowdhury.com/2013/01/solution-to-resolve-windows-phone-app-deployment-issue.html) - see end comment)

**Just to make it clear. I have not yet installed any other apps on this phone. It is a new phone**
 I also tried it on another phone of someone I know (but same type Lumia 920) and get the same error.

**Edit:** After registering on the Windows Phone Dev Center. I still get the same error even after unregistering and reregistering the phone. Strange thing is it says under my account under phones *"You haven't registered any phones."*, but I did.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you first use the Developer Registration Tool, it checks DevCenter for your permission level (there are different types of accounts that allow different amounts of unlocked devices and allowed installations).

Then, the tool unlocks the device and sets those permissions. (make sure the device is connected to the internet by itself, don't rely on the usb connection).

If you've had recent permission level changes or are changing to a new developer account, you may need to restart the phone to clear the old permissions after removing it from your DevCenter account.

To summarize:

1. Remove phone from DevCenter
2. Open Developer Registration Tool and plug in the phone. Confirm the device is no longer registered
3. Unplug and Reset the phone (Settings > About > Reset)
4. Set up the phone, connect to internet
5. Plug the phone back into the registration tool
6. Register the device again

Answer (score 2):

You can have an unlimited number of apps on your developer-unlocked phone from the Windows Store, but there is a limit of 10 developer apps that can be loaded onto a dev-unlocked phone at any time.  Once you have reached that limit, you must remove at least one of them from your developer phone in order to load another one onto the phone.  This is a simple solution and doesn't require unregistering & reregistering your phone.

Comment: This solved my issue but I can only have like 2 apps installed.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this, and then realized I still had my Windows 7 phone registered with the same name. I deleted that registration at https://dev.windowsphone.com/en-us/Account/Devices, unregistered and re-registered the Phone 8, and it now works. YMMV

Comment: Maybe I am just being silly. I don't have an account yet... So do I need to get an account before I can publish any applications to any phone?

Comment: Well If I had to... I did and still no luck

Answer (score 0):

I have brand new Lumia 620 and have the same error. The reason was in different country I set in my phone. Country of your microsoft account and the phone must be the same, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your applications list on your mobile and uninstall the developer applications, because you have limited developer apps on you phone.

Answer (score 0):

Check applications list and uninstall all other developer application.

Comment: Does this add anything beyond [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20737314/1711796) posted a few months ago?

Answer (score 0):

I think this step worked for me. Try manually deleting all files in Bin and obj folders of your project (not just clean project in VS)

Still having some issues with registering almost everyday the device as a developer. Do you experience this issue or only the error while deploying?