# Unable to install the application in windows device

Tags: deployment, windows-phone-8

I've **new Nokia Lumia 520 device and it is unlocked**. I've developed 2 applications. And I have successfully installed those applications. Now I've developed another application. When I try to deploy the applcation, I'm getting the below error.

```
unable to install the application. The maximum number of developer applications on this phone has been reached.
```

At the very first time when I registered, the device name is **Windows Phone**. When I get the above error, I google it. Then in windows phone developer blog, some developers said, **rename the device, unregister the device and re-register the device.**

So I've followed the same steps, but still I'm getting the same error, while deploying the application. Please help me how should I solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you phone is developer locked as a developer unlocked phone can have unlimited store apps, But there is a limit on developer apps in a developer unlocked phone. You get such problem once you reach the limit of the maximum apps. So, to deploy the app you need to uninstall current developer app in the phone.

you could refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16196318/the-maximum-number-of-developer-applications-on-this-phone-has-been-reached) post for more

Comment: Hi Amu, my device is unlocked device only.

Comment: two applications I have installed. Now I'm trying to install the third application. Then I'm getting the error.

Comment: If I uninstall any one of the developer application, then the third application is installing. At most I'm able to install two developer applications only. I'm not able to install the third developer application. I don't know what was wrong.